# Why doesn't scanf follow the docs with non-whitespace chars?

Tags: c, scanf

The [documentation on scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) says that any "Non-whitespace character" in the format, causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. **If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.**

However, if I run:

```
int x;
while(scanf("\n%d",&x)==1) printf("%d\n",x);
```

with the following input:

```
1 2
```

It prints:

```
1
2
```

Given that there's no '\n' preceding any of the two numbers, why does scanf read them? Isn't that against the docs?

Comment: newlines are considered whitespace and ignored by scanf.

Comment: Did you read the part about how scanf handles whitespace in the format?

Comment: Thanks both, Got it. The White space character section includes not only the <space>, but any "white space type character", which includes the new line. How do I mark the question as solved?

Comment: " How do I mark the question as solved? " - You can accept the answer by AShelly that answers your question ;)

Comment: It is not even necessary to put `"\n%d"` since the `%d` format ignores leading whitespace anyway. `"%d"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the same page that you link to and just before the paragraph you quoted, I see:

> - **Whitespace character:** the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the *format* string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the *stream* (including none).

A `\n` is a whitespace character.

Hence, the call

```
scanf("\n%d",&x)
```

will extract and discard any number of whitespace characters from `stdio` before reading data into `&x`.

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is a whitespace character. See [`isspace()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)